Css of data from CKeditor 5 doesn't work with Vue3 v-html built-in directive
I'm facing an issue with using CKEditor in a Vue project.
The edited data doesn't exactly match the displayed content using v-html, some CSS adjustments for images are not working as expected.
<template>
  <div class="editor-container__editor">
    <ckeditor
       v-if="isLayoutReady"
       v-model="editorData"
       :editor="editor"
       :config="config"
    />
  </div>

  <div style="margin: 20px 350px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000">
      <h2>Editor data display:</h2>
      <div v-html="editorData"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import {
  ClassicEditor,
  // Others
} from "ckeditor5";
import "ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css";
const isLayoutReady = ref(false);
const editorData = ref("");
const config = {
  // Some configuration
  image: {
    toolbar: [
      "toggleImageCaption",
      "imageTextAlternative",
      "|",
      "imageStyle:inline",
      "imageStyle:wrapText",
      "imageStyle:breakText",
      "|",
      "resizeImage",
    ],
  },
};
const editor = ClassicEditor;

onMounted(() => {
  isLayoutReady.value = true;
});
</script>

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something and not using ckeditor properly, the css from "ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css" seems to be what makes the editor work, but it won't apply to the data displayed with v-html, and I'm not sure what I need to do to address this issue.
